# 'NoneType' object is not callable error while attempting to click on an element returned with BeautifulSoup using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webdriver, click

I want to click on element targeted with beautifulsoup using click() method in selenium but this error is showing:

```
'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Example of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tabs = deals_tabs.find_all('div',{'class':'FilterSort__filter___36MvO'})
tabs.pop(0)
for tab in tabs:
    category = tab.text
    tab.click()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

### findall()

[`findall()`](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions#findall) finds all the matches and returns them as a list of **strings**, with each string representing one match.

So `tabs` is a *list* of *strings* as well as `tab`.

But [`click()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) is a WebElement method and can't be called on a *string*. Hence you see the error.